# Comet Streaming and HTTP Server

Tags: jetty, comet

I wish to create my own server. The requirements for the server are that it should serve html pages and also provide comet streaming functionality, but on the same port.
For comet, I find StreamHub to be a good resource, and I need a server like Jetty for serving web pages. How can i combine the two ( or use some other servers ) to suit my needs.

I do not want Comet by websockets or Long Polling. Please suggest all possible combinations for my needs. If possible, I'd like to host PHP pages on that too, but for now getting started with HTML should suffice.

Comment: maybe you can share some of your ideas so far, what conclusion you came to after your research

Comment: After exploring a little, I found jetty and streamhub as close solutions, but i cant run them on the same port. I also looked a little into COmetD but it doesn't suffice my needs. I need my own server because I want to add more functionalities to it later

Comment: this question shows little research.  example: Comet **is** long polling and/or websockets, but you reject it and want it at the same time.